# Python pivot table ValueError: negative dimensions are not allowed

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

I am trying to make a pivot table using a dataframe.

The columns I am using are the same size and have no missing data:

[image: the columns I am using are the same size and have no missing data]

When I input the following code:

```
bookmat = df_merge1.pivot_table(index='User-ID',columns='ISBN',values='Book-Rating')
bookmat.head()
```

I get an error.

```
    ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[117], line 1
----> 1 bookmat = df_merge1.pivot_table(index='User-ID',columns='ISBN',values='Book-Rating')
      2 bookmat.head()

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py:9190, in DataFrame.pivot_table(self, values, index, columns, aggfunc, fill_value, margins, dropna, margins_name, observed, sort)
   9173 @Substitution("")
   9174 @Appender(_shared_docs["pivot_table"])
   9175 def pivot_table(
   (...)
   9186     sort: bool = True,
   9187 ) -> DataFrame:
   9188     from pandas.core.reshape.pivot import pivot_table
-> 9190     return pivot_table(
   9191         self,
   9192         values=values,
   9193         index=index,
   9194         columns=columns,
   9195         aggfunc=aggfunc,
   9196         fill_value=fill_value,
   9197         margins=margins,
   9198         dropna=dropna,
   9199         margins_name=margins_name,
   9200         observed=observed,
   9201         sort=sort,
   9202     )

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\pivot.py:99, in pivot_table(data, values, index, columns, aggfunc, fill_value, margins, dropna, margins_name, observed, sort)
     96     table = concat(pieces, keys=keys, axis=1)
     97     return table.__finalize__(data, method="pivot_table")
---> 99 table = __internal_pivot_table(
    100     data,
    101     values,
    102     index,
    103     columns,
    104     aggfunc,
    105     fill_value,
    106     margins,
    107     dropna,
    108     margins_name,
    109     observed,
    110     sort,
    111 )
    112 return table.__finalize__(data, method="pivot_table")

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\pivot.py:189, in __internal_pivot_table(data, values, index, columns, aggfunc, fill_value, margins, dropna, margins_name, observed, sort)
    187         else:
    188             to_unstack.append(name)
--> 189     table = agged.unstack(to_unstack, fill_value=fill_value)
    191 if not dropna:
    192     if isinstance(table.index, MultiIndex):

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py:9622, in DataFrame.unstack(self, level, fill_value, sort)
   9558 """
   9559 Pivot a level of the (necessarily hierarchical) index labels.
   9560 
   (...)
   9618 dtype: float64
   9619 """
   9620 from pandas.core.reshape.reshape import unstack
-> 9622 result = unstack(self, level, fill_value, sort)
   9624 return result.__finalize__(self, method="unstack")

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\reshape.py:504, in unstack(obj, level, fill_value, sort)
    502 if isinstance(obj, DataFrame):
    503     if isinstance(obj.index, MultiIndex):
--> 504         return _unstack_frame(obj, level, fill_value=fill_value, sort=sort)
    505     else:
    506         return obj.T.stack(future_stack=True)

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\reshape.py:529, in _unstack_frame(obj, level, fill_value, sort)
    525 def _unstack_frame(
    526     obj: DataFrame, level, fill_value=None, sort: bool = True
    527 ) -> DataFrame:
    528     assert isinstance(obj.index, MultiIndex)  # checked by caller
--> 529     unstacker = _Unstacker(
    530         obj.index, level=level, constructor=obj._constructor, sort=sort
    531     )
    533     if not obj._can_fast_transpose:
    534         mgr = obj._mgr.unstack(unstacker, fill_value=fill_value)

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\reshape.py:154, in _Unstacker.__init__(self, index, level, constructor, sort)
    146 if num_cells > np.iinfo(np.int32).max:
    147     warnings.warn(
    148         f"The following operation may generate {num_cells} cells "
    149         f"in the resulting pandas object.",
    150         PerformanceWarning,
    151         stacklevel=find_stack_level(),
    152     )
--> 154 self._make_selectors()

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\reshape.py:206, in _Unstacker._make_selectors(self)
    203 self.full_shape = ngroups, stride
    205 selector = self.sorted_labels[-1] + stride * comp_index + self.lift
--> 206 mask = np.zeros(np.prod(self.full_shape), dtype=bool)
    207 mask.put(selector, True)
    209 if mask.sum() < len(self.index):

ValueError: negative dimensions are not allowed
```

I've tried everything I can think of to get the pivot table to work but there is always an error. I did merge two data frames on the 'ISBN' column to create the current dataframe, so I may have messed something up in that step. I am sure it's a simple fix that I am missing

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mre] and [edit] your question to include *all* necessary code and data [as text, not images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) to make it possible to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Show the full traceback of the error as properly formatted text (formatted as code) in the question.

Comment: I added the all of the code associated with the error. I hope that helps. thanks

Comment: I cannot be definitive but I think the error message, arising from Numpy, relates to a size limit; other reported cases all seem related to size. pivot_table uses grouping internally. You could try pivot_table on a somewhat reduced dataset to see what happens. ISBN is a unique value and you are asking for a million columns which is far beyond useful display; perhaps there is some other way to achieve whatever you have in mind if the pivot had worked.

Comment: Thank you. I reduced the data size and got the pivot table to work. So it seems like you were right.